# Form redirect with posted data

Tags: forms

How to transfer the submitted data *too* when redirecting a form through $form_data['#redirect']?

Like :

hook_menu declares : page-1, page-2

page-1 having a form that when submitted triggers page_1_form_submit() (in which I does the redirection)

but I'd like that once redirected to page-2, page_2_page() (registered as render function in hook_menu) can access the previously submitted data!

:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the form submission of the first page you can copy the values in `$form_state['values']` into the session for the current user; the page callback of the other page can then access them.

```
function mymodule_page1_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  $_SESSION['mymodule_page1_submission_timestamp'] = time();
  $_SESSION['mymodule_page1_submitted_values'] = $form_state['values'];


  $form_state['redirect'] = 'The path for the second page';
}

function mymodule_page2_view() {
  $delay = 300;
  if (!empty($_SESSION['mymodule_page1_submitted_values']) && !empty($_SESSION['mymodule_page1_submission_timestamp'])) {
    $submitted_data = ($_SESSION['mymodule_page1_submission_timestamp'] > time() - $delay) ? $_SESSION['mymodule_page1_submitted_values'] : array();
    unset($_SESSION['mymodule_page1_submission_timestamp']);
    unset($_SESSION['mymodule_page1_submitted_values']);       
  }

  // ...
}
```

I use `$_SESSION['mymodule_page1_submission_timestamp']` just to avoid the second page gets the values submitted on the form present in the first page more than 5 minutes before. If you don't want such restriction, then remove any reference to `$delay`.

You could also pass the values through the URL, but there is a restriction on the URL length the browsers can handle, and that restriction depends on the browser, as long as I know.

Comment: Excellent! Using $_SESSION and not to let the user alter the data is a good solution, I think. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

in your submit function , add your data  in the redirect url.

```
function page_1_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
$data_a = $form_state['values']['data_a_form'];
$data_b = $form_state['values']['data_b_form'];

$options = array(
    'query' => array(
         'data_a' => $data_a,
         'data_b' => $data_b,
        )
    );

$form_state['redirect'] = array('url_page2', $options);
}
```

The redirection will be

```
 www.domaine.com/url_page2?data_a=XXX&data_b=YYYY;
```

In the page_2 form, gather datas from $_GET variable

```
$data_a = $_GET['data_a'];
$data_b = $_GET['data_b'];
```

Don't forget to check your datas, like is_numeric, etc ...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know we can do it like this, but it might get tricky if some params are very long in size.

Comment: You right, look at this topic, the limit is higher than 2000 characters :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url